# while loop continues even if the condition is false

Tags: php

i'm trying do a while loop to access each results of a sql query

```
$request = $db->prepare("SELECT followerID FROM followers WHERE profile = ?");
$request->execute(array($_SESSION['id']));

while($user = $request->fetch()) 
{
var_dump($user);
}
```

and i get

```
array(2) { ["followerID"]=> string(2) "42" [0]=> string(2) "42" }
bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false)... (infinite)
```

I can see that the condition is false because when i do

```
var_dump($user = $request->fetch()) // multiple time
```

the first time I get the user informations but after this i get bool(false)

so the condition is false, but the loop continue, why ?

Comment: what's value of $user & $request->fetch( ) ... please update more info about data which is  you get in question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Comment: inside the while loop, the value of $user is array(2) { ["followerID"]=> string(2) "42" [0]=> string(2) "42" } for the first time, but after i get bool(false) because $request->fetch() returns false

Comment: @Progman thanks for your answer, I updated the question with more informations

Comment: @SkwalDev The code you have posted does not produce the output of `bool(false)`. Please recheck the help page [mcve] and add the source code which will generate the output you get in a way, that can be tested/verified by others.

Comment: @Progman i'm sorry, I changed my code to for(i = 0; i < $request->rowCount(); i++) and it worked

Comment: @SkwalDev Using `while()` and `fetch()` is totally fine and the common way to do it. However it looks like you have a `var_dump()` statement somewhere else and maybe some other loop in your code. If you add the MCVE we might be able to show you the issue.

Comment: **Off-topic - Cannot Reproduce** or **Needs Debugging Details**

Answer (score -1):

try this in order fetch records like this

```
$request = $conn->prepare("SELECT followerID FROM followers WHERE profile = ?");
$request->bind_param("i", $_SESSION['id']);
$request->execute();

$result = $request->get_result();

while($user = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
  var_dump($user);
}
```

i have seen that you are using SESSION variable make sure that you are calling **session_start()** on the the page

Comment: The OP is using PDO not MySQLi.